# Is there Photo Categories?

Tags: theme-development

I'm developing a theme, and there's a section for awards & certifications which will consist of just 4-6 small logos. Is there a way to put these images in a category and then display all of these images on the homepage with a simple code so the client won't have to go into the source code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically you can't put images in category, because they are not posts by themselves.

1. You can create [Custom Post Type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Types) for your images, etc, etc (might be overkill in your case).
2. Personally I like to use [Links](http://codex.wordpress.org/Links_Add_New_SubPanel) for such stuff. It is ready-made, easy to add images to (just URL), supports own categories and can be flexibly displayed, with [wp_list_bookmarks()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_bookmarks) or widget.

I did a post on such usage of links while back - [Make use of Links in WordPress](http://www.rarst.net/script/wordpress-links/).